# VSS 2005: how do I create branch at the point of a label?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe-2005, branching-and-merging

Using Visual SourceSafe 2005:

At an earlier point in time I labelled my source to indicate the release of a new version of the software.

What I want to do is now create a branch where the label was created, in order to release a minor upgrade without including other work that I have been doing on the software.

Do I use a branch for this, and how do I do this in VSS 2005?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean. However, go to your topmost level project folder then show history. You can click get on any label you see in the history. Please ensure you put this branch somewhere different to your current development branch.

Comment: I want to start a branch from where the label was added.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, just create a new folder for your release branch and get it from the label